# Converting a list of lists into a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

In Python how do I convert:

```
list01 = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['i', 'j', 'k'], ['x', 'y', 'z'] ]
```

into

```
list02 = [ 'abc', 'ijk', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(''.join, list01)
```

Or with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[''.join(x) for x in list01]
```

Both output:

```
['abc', 'ijk', 'xyz']
```

---

Note that in Python 3, `map` returns a map object instead of a list. If you do need a list, you can wrap it in `list(map(...))`, but at that point a list comprehension is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list01 = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['i', 'j', 'k'], ['x', 'y', 'z'] ]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in list01]
['abc', 'ijk', 'xyz']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> map(''.join, list01)
['abc', 'ijk', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` to implode the elements in a string and then append, if you don't want to use `map`.

```
# Your list
someList = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['i', 'j', 'k'], ['x', 'y', 'z'] ]
implodeList = []

# make an iteration with for in
for item in someList:
    implodeList.append(''.join(item))

# printing your new list
print(implodeList)
```

```
['abc', 'ijk', 'xyz']
```