# Outputting list of list as single string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about converting a list of list of integers to a single string in Python. The numbers in the sublist would be separated by a space and the sublists by a comma.

Like this:

```
input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
output = '1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9'
```

Comment: Probably via some code. You have shown none.

Comment: Don't name a variable `input`. Doing that replaces the `input` function.

Comment: `', '.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in s) for s in xnput)`

Comment: You can [join them together as a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105741/converting-a-list-of-lists-into-a-list-of-strings-python) and then you can use join again to turn them into one string.

Comment: @Johnny It doesn't replace it per se; it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it. Cf. [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In the future, please try solving the problem yourself first. There are multiple aspects to this task, and it's not clear which ones you need help with exactly, but thankfully we have existing questions that cover all of them, so I've closed your post accordingly. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you can use the join function in python to achieve the result

```py
print(", ".join([ " ".join([str(a) for a in x]) for x in input]))
```

PS:

if you want to concatenate the list, there is a chain functionality in itertools that can help you achieve this

```py
from itertools import chain

input = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(list(chain(*input)))
```

although you should try to do it with simple loops first as well for your practice and building logic

Comment: This outputs `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` which is different than the OP's desired output of `1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9`